# Vuex for Vuejs2. Using commit

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am new to vue, and although I have made my code work. I'm not sure if this is intended. Is there another way to update vuex state without having to call `.commit` and pass in a string representation of the method name? This seems counter intutive. There was a guide I ran across that passed into the mutation function a `{ commit }` object, but this syntax seemed overly complex is there an alternate? Here is my code.

> Store

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
   state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    increment (state) {
      state.count++
      console.log(this.state.count)
    },
    decrement (state) {
      state.count--
      console.log(this.state.count)
    }
  }
})
```

> Counter

```
<template>
  <div class="counter">
    <h1>{{ initialCount }}</h1>
    <h2>{{ computedCounter }}</h2>
    <button @click="increment">+</button>
    <button @click="decrement">-</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { store } from '../store/store.js'

export default {
  name: 'Counter',
  store: store,
  data () {
    return {
      initialCount: store.state.count
    }
  },
  computed: {
    computedCounter () {
      return store.state.count
    }
  },
  methods: {
    increment () {
      store.commit('increment') <--- not a big fan.
    },
    decrement () {
      store.commit('decrement') <--- also not a fan.
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [recommended](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html) way of doing this is to use constants for Mutation Types, i.e:

```
// mutation-types.js
export const SOME_MUTATION = 'SOME_MUTATION'

// actions.js
import * as types from './mutation-types'
const increment = ({ commit }) => {
  commit(types.SOME_MUTATION);
};

// store.js
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import { SOME_MUTATION } from './mutation-types'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: { ... },
  mutations: {
    // we can use the ES2015 computed property name feature
    // to use a constant as the function name
    [SOME_MUTATION] (state) {
      // mutate state
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: and suddenly, this seems to blow everything up in terms of verbosity. I also dont understand what is going on now.

Comment: Vuex has integration with the chrome vue dev tools, which allows you to see every mutation and it's effect on the state. It's pretty useful.

Comment: I think it does make sense, because the idea of vuex or redux is for everything to go through a centralized state manager. And as all mutations are all constants, all components share only one single state at any given time. And Vuex adopts the "one-way data flow" philosophy to enforce states to be [only mutated in a predictable fashion](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html).

Comment: This answer seems very incomplete. For one I don't see how to actually use this. Should I use the action now instead of the store in my component? Do i need the brackets for `[SOME_MUTATION]` mutation method to work?

Comment: `[SOME_MUTATION]` is a ES2015 or ES6 syntax for [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer), as pointed our in the comment as well. If you are not familiar with this particular syntax, I suggest you start from learning that first, since it is pretty much the industry standard now.